# Can't connect to query console (8000) despite success on 8001 and 8002

Tags: marklogic

I just installed the MarkLogic server (MarkLogic-9.0-8.2-amd64.msi) on Windows 10 and requested/received a developer license.

**I can't connect to the query console on localhost:8000.** I get a browser "can't connect error", not any error response from the MarkLogic server.

I **can** connect to the admin page on port 8001 and the configuration manager on 8002. I'm logged in as an admin user and I even granted myself the qconsole-user role, logged out and then back in.

Comment: I haven't seen this error before. Simplest way out might be to uninstall, and reinstall MarkLogic. It will preserve any data you might already have loaded.

Comment: If that doesn't help, I'd reach out to support if you are entitled. You could also have a look at Admin UI, Status tab. There should be an App-Services appserver showing healthy status. Is that the case?

Comment: getting familiar with the status tab was helpful, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any chance that port 8000 has been taken by another process?

Comment: To check port is assign or not, type following command on your cmd run as administrator:
netstat -na | find "8000"

Comment: Amazon workdocs (like dropbox) was using 8000.  Thanks!  I reassigned the query console to port 8009 in the config tab, and now I can visit it.